# Can I convert Android Application to IPhone/IPad Application?

Tags: java, android, iphone, ios

Can I convert Android Application to IPhone/IPad (IOS right?) Application? How can I do it? I am a Java developer, and I know android. I went through a Free and OpenSource Project called In-The-Box, but it seems to be dead. Please help

**UPDATE**

Update because everyone says it is not possible.

This is the project I have mentioned. http://www.flexycore.com/ispectrum-overview.html

Can anyone please tell me whether this is dead or not? Why they have no downloads?

Comment: learn Objective-C language

Comment: Try to develop your application with Phonegap. Because Android and Iphone are different platform. if you are using phonegap means you can able to create application for all smartphones.

Comment: @Prateek: Can't and will not use in this case. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @Sepala Is your Andoid application developed in html5 or java

Comment: @Prateek: XML for GUI. Java for Other stuff

Comment: then there is no way for you to convert that application to iOS. You need to hire someone if you can't learn it.. Hope this info helps you

Comment: @Prateek: Even though I need to have that developer license or something right? hmmm...Too much cost. I don't have a MAC. One person asks me whether I can do it, no time for learning. Thats why I am seeking for alternatives. I don't have an IPhone too!! They are too much cost :(

Comment: @Sepala The only way to develop iOS application without mac is phonegap only. You can convert your existing Android application to html5 through phonegap and make it same for iOS.

Comment: @Prateek: OK, so using phonegape it is possible???? Right???

Comment: @Sepala YES it's possible

Comment: Calm down @Sepala Everyone has different thoughts about your question. And anyone has full right to upvote/downvote/close your question. And regarding your converting Android app to iOS. Follow these steps 1. Learn Objective-C, 2. Learn developing iOS app. Some users might have suggested you the PhoneGap/Monotouch(etc etc). The only thing I suggest you that these framework can never be as fast as your native code. As you are java developer so it's no hard to learn Obj-C. But if you are really brilliant in JS/HTML5/CSS then you can mimic native look and feel but not 100%

Comment: OK. I decided to cancel the app. Will do it after learning it

Comment: @Sepala : Apparently the project you mentioned does not "convert" the application source code. Instead it provides an intermediate platform to host the application on a different platform. Is this you actually need?

Comment: If u  use `corona`, u can develop for both android and ios. It uses the `lua` language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such way (Practically convenient) to convert an existing application, if you haven't think about it beforehand. The language concepts are too "different"

If you have used a cross platform framework such as HTML, CSS, JavaScript or PhoneGap this is feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since your answer contains details about PhoneGap, I am marking this as the answer. Anyway, is phoneGap another language?

Comment: Not exactly. You can say a wrapper. But there are some limitations like limited device access capabilities. So this may not resolve your question but worth to have a look. http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/mobile/3037-getting-started-with-phonegap.html

Answer (score 5):

Android is usually built with the java like language, on the IPhone you do your coding in ObjectiveC. Obviously these are completely different entities, so you cannot share code and logic between them.

You can look into "generic" solutions like MonoDroid, MonoTouch which share .net style coding, or you can go towards "phonegap" like HTML5 style cross platform solutions.

In order to convert Android apps on iPhones you need an excellent knowledge of the techniques involved in sloting programs from Android based management system to Apple’s OS.While the porting process may not be as smooth or as easy as one might wish it to be, the idea -pretty much remains the same. The whole idea is to extract as much information as possible from the earlier Android based apps and apply innovative techniques to convert those to iPhone compatible ones.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296545/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-android-application-to-ipad-iphone).

This [link](http://workmonk.com/service/convert-android-app-iphone-app) will help you.

Comment: Thanks for +1, but i wonder where my answer lacks, i included phonegap, titanium, html5 etc :( And I was the first one to answer.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya +1 from me.. Don't be disheartened, OP has every right to  choose any answer as accepted. It is his/her choice, and that fact you answered first does not matter in any way. Forget about the reputation and never consider stackoverflow as a game. Consider it as a place where you can discuss with awesome programmers about advanced programming, a place to learn..

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Hi. The reason for choosing the other answers is, it is the first one to come up with phonegap. Your answer came with phonegap after the edit, but that answer came faster than the edit. :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Oh and, there is another reason for me to not to select your answer. That is, one of your link takes me to a PAID service. So I have to pay them and get the help. I didn't expect that, and not going to do that as well.I am talking about your last link, it is a link to a paid service.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a tool that does it (at least they tell it does), called [j2objc](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/). Disclaimer : I never tried it, and never believe them.

Now your (practical)options are:

1) Learn objective - C,and code from scratch ( and thank me later for this suggestion).

2) Try to use some cross platform tools like PhoneGap, Appcelerator. (If you yet to do your android app)

Comment: I went through it. It says "NON GUI CODE" CAN BE converted. Who is gonna have NON GUI code for phones :D

Comment: Also, just to add, it requires MAC machine, which is mandatory

Comment: Sepala Yes, you may be right.. As I say, I never tried it, and wouldn't recommend it.. @Prateek, OP doesn't said anywhere that he is doesn't have a mac machine, or not intending to buy one. Also if he is serious about doing iOS in future, A mac is really handy..

Comment: Oops, OP doesn't have one.. sorry didn't see the comment.. Still my suggestion stands, he will never regret buying one..

Answer (score -2):

There is no safe and easy way to convert Android apps to iOS thought lazy people are looking for that quite often. Any serious project is always coded from scratch for both (or more) platforms.

Comment: There are lot of apps using Phonegap/appcelerator available in stores.. Not every person/company has the time/resources to invest in both.. I am also believe (just like you) that coding separately for both platform is much better. But developers using cross platform solutions are not lazy, and this no way answers the question.