# Android to iOS - suggestion

Tags: android, ios, iphone, xcode, j2objc

I have created an app in Android Studio. I want to make it work on iOS too. Is it possible to open it in xcode and somehow translate it to obj C and build it to make it work? 
EDIT: I have seen j2objc project but I can't figure out how it works...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to convert Android Application to IPad, IPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296545/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-android-application-to-ipad-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible although there are Java to C++ converters but android to ios,I don't think so you'll have to create new application for ios in **swift** (xcode).I don't know about j2objc but I still think its better to develop fresh application for a new language.

Comment: I started it already... I hope it wont take me too long to create it...

Comment: Awesome best of luck then