# How to get my android app to work on apple devices

Tags: android, ios

So I created an app on android studio and now my boss wants me to get it to work on Apple devices.

Is there a short cut to get an Android App to work on Apple devices ie iPhones, iPads and so on.

I really don't wanna create a whole other version for Apple devices.

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296545/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-android-application-to-ipad-iphone)!, there's a couple of detailed answers on there already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible. An option is to create hybrid application using [Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/) or [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) which will run on both iOS and Android. That means you need to migrate you current implementation to hybrid app.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to do it and each of them has pros and cons so choose wisely.

**Hybrid App**

A hybrid app allows you to build a cross-platform mobile application with web technology. There are plenty of options you can use like [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/), [PhoneGap](https://phonegap.com/) or [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). But since you have built an Android app with the native code I assume, those existent features need to be rewritten in order to run on an iOS device.

**[Xamarin](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/)/[Flutter](https://flutter.dev)**

They are both create a native-like experience. The advantage of them comparing with hybrid app technology is the performance would be better in general. But again, it doesn't mean that you can just create an iOS app without changing any code, you'll still need to rewrite most of part in your app.

**[Kotlin Native](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/mpp-ios-android.html)**

As an android developer, you're probably familiar with Kotlin. It's officially supported by Android team and It's 100% interoperable with Java. Kotlin can also be compiled to run on multiplatform including iOS. By this way, you'll be able to reuse a lot of existing Kotlin code on both Android and iOS so you don't need to use a new language to rewrite all the functionalities you had done on Android. The cons are It's an experimental feature so It's young and could change on the future and the reusability doesn't mean that you don't need to learn iOS platform.